# Modelling an A to B movement controller, split or merge position and movement as state machines

Tags: finite-state-machine

I am currently creating a software model for controlling a simple (two-way) pneumatic cylinder. In essence, this controls just a movement from point A to point B. The controller has two outputs (OnMovingToA, OnMovingToB), which can be linked to a relay, valve, etc... to move the actuator to resp. A or B. The controller has two inputs (AtPositionA, AtPositionB) representing end-stops: a feedback mechanism that the position has been reached.

A user can interact with the controller/cylinder using commands/functions: `MoveToA` and `MoveToB`.

- Upon calling `MoveToA`, the cylinder should move to `A` and stop when `A` has been reached (`AtPositionA` is true).
- Upon calling `MoveToB`, the cylinder should move to `B` and stop when `B` has been reached (`AtPositionB` is true).

[image: double acting cylinder]

Sometimes we also use 3-state valves to control the cylinder, where the cylinder can also be stopped halfway. Therefore the command `Stop` is added as well.

- When `Stop` is called during a movement, the cylinder most likely will stop in an undetermined `intermediate position`. The system then waits for the next `MoveToA` or `MoveToB`

[image]

Inside the controller, I use a state machine. Initially, I had the state machine of the controller modeled like this:

[image: position and movement merged]

some remarks:

- The rising edge of `AtPositionA` is `A reached`
- The falling edge of `AtPositionA` is `A left`
- The rising edge of `AtPositionB` is `B reached`
- The falling edge of `AtPositionB` is `B left`
- With A left, I mean: exit the A position.
- With B left, I mean: exit the B position.
- Output `OnMovingToA` is set to true when `Moving to A` is active.
- Output `OnMovingToB` is set to true when `Moving to B` is active.

At least one issue I have with the above is that, since we are dealing with real-world applications, it is possible to be at position A and to move to B simultaneously. (the cylinder can be blocked, or the end-stop can have some off-delay. Naturally, this is not allowed within state machines, so we have to work around this.

After giving it some thought, I figured that position and movement are in fact 2 different - although connected - properties of a system. Hence, I split the state machine into movement and position states:

[image]

I feel that the second one is the way to go, but I fear that this is a bit unconventional.

**What state machine would be preferred in this scenario? Is this a matter of taste, or is there a clear guideline that puts one above the other?**

Comment: You named two inputs, but then don't use those names in the state diagrams.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, I modified my question

Answer (score 2):

Splitting position and movement is a good way to simplify the state machine model. But we can do better. Change what you're modeling.

"The controller has two outputs (OnMovingToA, OnMovingToB)"
"The controller has two inputs (AtPositionA, AtPositionB)"

[image]

```
Input\Command | OnMovingToA OnMovingToB Idle
--------------+-----------------------------            
AtPositionA   | OnMovingToB OnMovingToB OnMovingToB 
AtPositionB   | OnMovingToA OnMovingToA OnMovingToA
AtPositionI   | OnMovingToA OnMovingToB OnMovingToA
```

Rather than model the piston, lets model what we want the controller to do. Here we're taking the previous controller command as state and position as input. The result is both the output and the new command state. This is enough to keep the piston moving. This way, rather than trying to remember how the piston should be moving we look at how we're telling the piston to move.

`Idle` can be thought of as meaning there is no previous command. The result of `Idle` `AtPositionI` is `OnMovingToA` arbitrarily, just to get things moving at start up. Otherwise it's unreachable. `AtPositionI` simply means not getting either position signal. If you're getting them both, something is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Am I correct to understand that the controller that you have modeled is continuously moving back and forth? I went back to my question and saw that I didn't mention how the client interacts with the controller, so I have added that. The user basically has 3 buttons to interact with: `MoveToA`, `MoveToB` and `Stop`. Does that still go with what you had in mind?

Comment: @CédricMoers that's called an answer invalidating edit. At this point your question is under specified. It's not clear what should happen after the user presses `MoveToA`. Should it stop at A? Should it resume cycling? Do we even need the controller since the user is acting as one? You could add 3 "overridden" states to stop the automatic cycling. They'd just reflect whatever button had just been pressed. But if these 3 buttons stop the cycling, you have no way to resume cycling. So yes, the controller continuously moves the piston back and forth. If you wanted something else, be clear

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I wasn't aware of 'answer invalidating edits' being bad practice. I will make sure my questions are better defined from the start. The controller has the sole purpose of Moving towards A until A is reached (AtPositionA is `true`), the same goes for B. So there is no cycling involved, sorry that this was not clear.

Comment: @CédricMoers So when the controller is told "Move to A" with a momentary button push the controller must send, and continue to send, a "Move to A" signal to the piston until the piston signals it's at A. At that point the controller must stop that signal and idle.  Same for B.  Have I got that right?

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for this answer not matching the question. The OP has yet to incorporate clarifying comments into the question.

---

[Your comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439767/modelling-an-a-to-b-movement-controller-split-or-merge-position-and-movement-as/439789#comment965311_439775) clarified that the controller should not cycle the piston on its own. Here's an answer based on that clarification.

I still prefer modeling the controller rather than the piston. But I think we got shorted some inputs and outputs.

"The controller has <strike>two</strike> three inputs (AtPositionA, AtPositionB, *AtPositionI*)"
"The controller has <strike>two</strike> three outputs (OnMovingToA, OnMovingToB, *OnIdle*)"
The controller apparently has [buttons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439767/modelling-an-a-to-b-movement-controller-split-or-merge-position-and-movement-as/439789#comment965301_439775) that force these outputs/states. They have different names printed on the labels but the wires don't care.

That's better. This moore style FSM transition table has the controller maintain the last command until the goal is reached or it's stopped (made to idle):

```
Input\Command | OnMovingToA OnMovingToB OnIdle
--------------+-------------------------------            
AtPositionA   | OnIdle      OnMovingToB OnIdle        
AtPositionB   | OnMovingToA OnIdle      OnIdle        
AtPositionI   | OnMovingToA OnMovingToB OnIdle
```

Each button press of the controller is a state change. This state machine controls when that button press is considered over based on the position inputs. The user controls when it starts.

There is a potential bug. When implementing this the button press state change could produce output without reading position. A `OnMovingToA` command could be issued when already `AtPositionA`. Avoidable but also easy to overlook. If critical a Mealy style FSM might model this better.